# JSP internationalization with language

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, jstl

I have a problem with jstl. 
How i can set in a index.jsp page the language to be used in all jsp pages messages of my application? I want that the default is the browser local but also i have implemented a dropdown menu that pass a language parameter to the page such as the result is index.jsp?lang=en_US and  i want that the user from now will see all jsp of the application in en_US language.

What code i need to put into the other jsp?
If a declare a variable with scope session why i can't get its value in the others jsp?

Here is the example code i used in the index.jsp

```
<c:set var="languageParameter" value="${param.language}" />
<c:if test="${languageParameter !=undefined}">
    <c:set var="basename" value='it.example.com.i18n.' />
    <c:set var="basenameLocale" value="${basename}${languageParameter}" />
</c:if>
<c:if test="${languageParameter ==undefined}">
    <c:set var="localeCode" value="${pageContext.response.locale}" />
    <c:set var="basename" value='it.example.com.i18n.' />
    <c:set var="basenameLocale" value="${basename}${localeCode}" scope="session"/>
</c:if>
```